# What's the difference between a figure, a number and a digit?

Tags: numbers

A dictionary says:

Figure: a symbol for a number

Digit: a word, letter, symbol, or figure representing a number.

Number: a mathematical unit used to count or express an amount, quantity.

I don't see a big difference between a figure and a digit. What is it?

Answer (score 6):

You're using a select subset of many definitions for figure, number, and digit.

A [digit](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/digit) is a single numeral (0-9), like the digit **5** in the number **5**, or the digit **5** in the number **2507**.

A [number](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/number) can have one or more digits, like **7** or **2507** or **2,507.38**.

A [figure](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/figure) can be a shape, a diagram, or a number; if used to describe a number, it can be composed of a single digit or of multiple digits.

Comment: "2507" is a _single numerical value_ but not a digit.

Answer (score 5):

A [**figure**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/figure) is something that is drawn, which might be *digit*.

A *figure* can also be a *number* or amount, for example in this dialogue:

> We will need to pay them off.
> What figure do you have in mind?
> I suggest 10,000 should be enough.

---

A [**digit**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/digit) is a single *number* in the range 0 to 9. It is the same word for fingers/thumbs and toes, of which we have 10 each.

Sometimes *digit* and *figure* can be used interchangeably.

> 10,000 is a five figure sum.

In computer parlance, each of those *figures* is referred to as a *digit*.

---

A [**number**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/number) is an arithmetical quantity, which is written using *digits* and other symbols, such as a sign and a decimal point.

Comment: +1, there's also "numeral," which can be roughly synonymous with "digit."